# Xcode connect on demand on webdriveragent

Tags: ios, xcode, selenium-webdriver, appium

When I'm trying to test the webdriveragent on Xcode using iOS 17.2, I never used to get this message but now it keeps saying that it will connect on demand. The web driver agent never installs on the device. Has anybody run into this?

Also, my Mac keeps restarting when I'm working in Xcode and, with every restart, Xcode forgets that it has 17.2 already installed. Then I have to do a hard reboot and this is where I ran into this

[image: issue]

It was supposed to just install webdriveragent on the device so I can start at appium and connect to the device and start running my automation.

Answer (score 0):

I also installed the web driver agent and observed that the " will connect on demand" message appears when my Mac or iPhone is connected to a VPN. So I disconnect both devices from the VPN to successfully finish the installation.